# JSF: listener inside p:dataGrid not invoked

Tags: jsf, datagrid, listener

Ajax listener is not invoked when it's inside p:dataGrid:

Code like the following works (listener is invoked):

```
<h:form id="test">
  <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="test" value="false">
    <p:ajax listener="#{controller.valueChange()}" process="@this" />
       <h:outputText value="TEST" />                                          
  </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
</h:form>
```

But when I surround it with dataGrid:

```
<p:dataGrid value="#{model.myItems}" var="item">
  //form
</p:dataGrid>
```

It doesn't work anymore. I can see that some POST is called (from browser) but listener is not invoked.

The same problem is with `<p:ajax listener="...">` and `valueChangeListener` (as attribute of `h:selectBooleanCheckbox`).

What is wrong? How can I combine listeners with dataGrid?

Comment: Did you exclude #4 of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandlink-commandbutton-ajax-backing-bean-action-listener-method-not-invoked/2120183#2120183?

Comment: Many thanks !! Point No. 4 helped me! - putting the bean in the view scope and load the data model in @PostConstruct